# Compile Error Relating To ActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting compile warning: "Imcompatable pointer types sending UIToolbar to Parameter type UITabBar" at line "[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.navigationController.toolbar];".

I know this is wrong but it works and I don't know how to make it work without the warning.

```
- (void)share
{
    // Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://getsharekit.com"];
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"ShareKit is Awesome!"];

    // Get the ShareKit action sheet
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

    // Display the action sheet
    [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

Comment: @Faisal: In which class you have above share function ? i mean in whether in UIViewController inherited class OR other class

Comment: It is a UITableViewController

Comment: @Faisal: your code look me correct,and are passing the correct type ..

Comment: @Faisal: Is it error Or warning ?

Comment: @Faisal: Just avoid it and see how much does it cost you ..

Comment: OK, i guess i will do that.  Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769629/uitableview-crashing-when-editing/5769657#5769657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue seems to be here;

```
 [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

Shouldn't you be saying;

```
 [actionSheet showFromToolBar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

ToolBars and TabBars are different types, hence your warning.

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to say but I don't have a toolbar, only a navbar and tabbar.

Comment: self.navigationController.toolbar IS however a toolbar, not a tabbar. The warning is telling you exactly what the problem is. Either pass a tabbar to the showFromTabBar method or pass a toolbar to the showFromToolbar method. Either way will be correct, what you have now is mixing them up and whilst it will work as they are both UIView subclasses, the compiler is correctly warning you that you may not get the behaviour your expect.

Comment: Thanks, if i do `[actionSheet showFromTabBar:` what do i add after that?