# UITableView Crashing When Editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Getting error at line:         `[self.routineTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];`

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[self.routineTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

if(editing){
    [self.routineTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
} else {
    // delete section
}
```

}

Update:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you return **current number of sections** after update. This means you'll need a way to track number of sections, example in a private variable `currentNumberOfSections` that should be `NSInteger`. Increment it after each insert (decrement in case you're removing a section). And don't forget to update your `-numberOfSectionsInTableView` method in your `TableViewController` to something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return currentNumberOfSections;
}
```

Check that you are returning the current number of sections for the `TableViewController`, in which you're adding the new section.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[self.routineTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

if(editing){
    [self.routineTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    currentNumberOfSections++;
} else {
    // delete section
}
```

And then in the class referenced by `self.routineTableView` add/update:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return currentNumberOfSections;
}
```

Don't forget to add `NSInteger currentNumberOfSections` to controller's header file. I would also put it in `@private` section, but this is up to you. In the designated initializer of the controller set the value of this variable to preferred default number of sections: `currentNumberOfSections = 1`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ziggy.  I understand what you are saying but I'm still confused as to what I have to do to fix this.  I just added `numberOfSections` method to question.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're inserting a section into `self.routineTableView` and returns the number of sections from a different controller `self.fetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Thanks, but if i replace `return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];` with `return currentNumberOfSections;`, wont this cause problems when loading initially?

Comment: Good point. Add `currentNumberOfSections = 1` to the initializer. If `1` is the default number of sections in this table.

Comment: the thing is, the table should always have 1 section, i never add sections.  i think the problem is with adding/deleting rows, not sections.

Comment: I just deleted that whole method, turns out I didn't even need it. Thanks!